# LINQ string casting error when returning a byte array

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to store hashes and salts in a database using entity framework. But when I try to call this code to return one of the salts.

```
var salt = (from u in db.Users
            join p in db.Passwords on u.Name equals p.UserName
            where u.Name == username
            select p.Salt).First();
```

I get thrown this exception:
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'.'

My Password entity looks like this:

```
    class Password
    {
        [Key]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public byte[] Hash { get; set; }
        public byte[] Salt { get; set; }
        public User User{ get; set;}
    }
```

Comment: What are the actual data types in your database for the columns?

Comment: What is the definition of `Hash` and `Salt` in the passwords table?

Comment: @jeroenh they are nvarchar

Comment: Then that is your error. Why do you define them as `byte[]` in code? LINQ can not magically cast string to byte[]

Comment: @jeroenh allright thanks

Comment: @jeroenh EF can, at least in EF core starting from 2.1.

Comment: @Tanveer yes, but not without extra configuration, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table's columns are likely varchar or something similar, rather than binary/varbinary data types - or whatever term your database server uses for storing binary data.

If you are using EF core, then see [value converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions). There's a `StringToBytesConverter` available.